# Camel how to clear the cache of LRUCache at the end of router?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

From this page: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sftp-component.html, I see that if idempotent=true, LRUCache will hold 1000 entries to avoid consuming the same files over and over again, it's really good option.

However if I want to test that file again, I have to stop and start so that LRUCache will be cleared (that's what I thought camel works on that way), so how to clear the LRUCache at the end of my router - java so that I can test the file again, don't have to stop and start again? (this is just for local development, easier to test).

While searching in camel code, I see there is LRUCache and method cleanUp, but don't know how to call it.

Thanks